# Length operation within a newtcblisting

Tags: macros, listings, calculations, tcolorbox, lengths

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings,skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\numlen}
\newcommand{\getnumlen}[1]{
    \setlength{\numlen}{\widthof{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1 0123456789}}
    \setlength{\numlen}{0.1\numlen}
}
\newtcblisting{mytcblisting}[1][]{
    before = {\getnumlen{#1}},
    enhanced,
    left = 4.\numlen,%\numlen is correct here
    listing only,
    listing options = {
        language = C++,
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        showstringspaces = false,
        numbers = left,
        numbersep = 4.\numlen,%\numlen seems to be 0 here
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytcblisting}[\tiny]
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
\end{mytcblisting}
\end{document}
```

I would like the `left` measure and the separation between the numbers and the code `numbersep` be based on the typical length of a number written in the `cmtt` family with the size passed as an argument of `mytcblisting`.

But with this code, the `left` option works well, but not the `numbersep`.

How to make it work?

Comment: Apparently `tcblisting` evaluates `listing options` before `\before`, having a zero value then. You can see this, if you set `\setlength{\newlength}{20pt}` in the preamble -- it will use this value then for the spacing.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I was assuming that was the origin of the problem... but the question remains: how to make it work (have the `numbersep` based on the size passed as argument `#1`)?

Comment: Well, I looked into `listings` to get some clue what could be done from that side that `\getnumlen{#1}` could be called there as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Does that mean that you have a working solution? If so, how to call `\getnumlen{#1}` in the listing options?

Comment: No, I have no solution, because I found nothing where I can *inject* this code

Comment: I've posted a solution, but this will print the numbers outside of the box

Comment: Just replace `before={...}` by `code={...}`. This `code` is executed immediately, but `before` is used later when the box is drawn.

Comment: `code` is a very hidden option in `tcolorbox` documentation ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But I did not hide it with intention ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `listing options` is evaluated before `before=\getnumlen{#1}` is used and `numlen` set. This means that `numlen` is `0pt` --> the `\getnumlen{#1}` must be called in this special option block (too).

A dirty trial --> Use `\getnumlen{#1}` in `basicstyle` option --> it's an effective code macro and no typesetting/font macro, so it should not harm there.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings,skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\numlen}
\newcommand{\getnumlen}[1]{%
  \setlength{\numlen}{\widthof{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1 0123456789}}%
  \setlength{\numlen}{0.1\numlen}%
}
\newtcblisting{mytcblisting}[1][]{%
    listing options = {%
        language = C++,
        basicstyle=\getnumlen{#1}\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        showstringspaces = false,
        numbers = left,
        numbersep = 4.\numlen,%\numlen seems to be 0 here
    },%
    before = {\getnumlen{#1}},
    enhanced,
    left = 4.\numlen,%\numlen is correct here
    listing only
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytcblisting}[\tiny]
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
\end{mytcblisting}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** A cleaner way: Add a key to the `lst` key family:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings,skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\define@key{lst}{numlen}[\protect\tiny]{%%
  \getnumlen{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\numlen}
\newcommand{\getnumlen}[1]{%
  \setlength{\numlen}{\widthof{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1 0123456789}}%
  \setlength{\numlen}{0.1\numlen}%
}
\newtcblisting{mytcblisting}[1][]{%
    listing options = {%
        language = C++,
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1,
        showstringspaces = false,
        numbers = left,
        numlen={\protect #1},
        numbersep = 6.\numlen,%\numlen seems to be 0 here
    },%
    before = {\getnumlen{\protect #1}},
    enhanced,
    left = 4.\numlen,%\numlen is correct here
    listing only
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytcblisting}[\tiny]
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
\end{mytcblisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In the edited example, I guess it's `\protect #1` instead of `\protect\tiny`

Comment: @Vincent: Yes, you're right. A typo. But it works too -- well, works in the sense that `numlen` isn't zero any longer.